# Chipped Bottom Navigation for Java in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bottomnavigationview

I have seen a `chipped bottom navigation` for `kotlin` and is wondering if there is any such library for `java` and can we use the `kotlin` library in `java`.

Comment: of course you can use libraries that write with kotlin in your java code. can you share  the mentioned library?

Comment: https://github.com/ismaeldivita/chip-navigation-bar. This is github repository

Comment: I created a lightweight dependency in java: https://github.com/shubham-gupta-16/Super-Bottom-Navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in: [Mixing Java and Kotlin in one project](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/mixing-java-kotlin-intellij.html);
You can use kotlin code in your java project.

so add the `chipped bottom navigation` to your project dependecy. and use that.

Comment: Give it a try: https://github.com/shubham-gupta-16/Super-Bottom-Navigation